# Signal/Slot mechanism for Perl

Tags: perl

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to Qt's signal/slot mechanism for Perl.  I have looked into POE, but since it's huge, I couldn't find anything useful.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [Object::Event](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Object-Event), an API for registering and emitting events, mostly for [AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/AnyEvent), but I imagine you could use it elsewhere.  [Gtk2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2) also has a mechanism similar to QT's, especially combined with [Glade XML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Gtk2-GladeXML/), which lets you automatically map event slots|signals to perl object methods or functions.  AnyEvent is a generic event loop which supports Gtk/Glib and POE, amongst others, and is much easier to grok than the large set of modules that is POE.

Answer (score 1):

The concept is generally called [Publish/Subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe). The search result for [`pubsub` on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=pubsub&mode=all) gives you what you want.